# Where is the gem command in RHEL6?

Tags: linux, redhat, ruby

I just built RHEL 6 and I need to be able to install ruby gems, etc. I have the ruby 1.8.7 packages installed but there is no gem command anywhere? What gives?

Comment: Have you tried `find / --name gem`? If it's a new system it shouldn't take too long to search. If that doesn't return any results it might not be installed, do a `yum list *gem*`, pick the most relevant result and install it. Not really a proper answer (Unless it works, in which case it was ^_^)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably have to install RubyGems. Try:

```
yum install rubygems
```

If it fails, try installing it by hand:

```
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/74922/rubygems-1.8.4.tgz
tar xzpvf rubygems-1.8.4.tgz
cd rubygems-1.8.4
ruby setup.rb
```

Comment: While this works, I think it would be more ideal to install via yum and a system configured repository, rather than installing one-off RPMs.

Comment: [Updated link on rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/pages/download). Also, note that to use yum you need your RH subscription to be up-to-date and that subscriptions don't seem to be backward compatible - meaning if your department upgrades then you must also upgrade as the older subscription expires. This also applies to using rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below:

## whereis gem

/usr/local/bin/gem

## cp /usr/local/bin/gem /sbin

## gem -v

2.5.1

Comment: This question has already been resolved. Also, when formatting code, please use `code formatting` instead of **bold letters.**